# How to set left and top in a Positioned widget in pixels or any other units in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-positioned

How can I set the left and top of a `Positioned` widget in pixels or any other units in Flutter/Dart?

What unit are the left and top values in? Are they in percents or independent pixels or something? If not, what unit does it use?

Comment: they are "logical pixels", see [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/devicePixelRatio.html) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
       height: 200,
       width: 200,
       color: Colors.red,
    ),
    // postion will be based on up Container Widget
    // position top left
    const Positioned(
       left: 0,
       top: 0,
       child: CircleAvatar(
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
       ),
    ),
    // position bottom right
    const Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: CircleAvatar(
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
     ),
  ],
),
```

If you don't give any position. The position will be based on Stack alignment.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for the code! Is there any way to get the screen size? I tried using MediaQuery but didn't work. I returned a MaterialApp but still I'm not able to use the build context.